# How to use GCDAsyncUdpSocket for multicast over wifi and bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, udp, multicast, gcdasyncsocket

I am currently using GCDAsyncUdpSocket to send multicast datagrams over wifi between iOS devices.

The Code is pretty simple..

Client

```
self.socket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self  delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

//omitted error checking
[self.socket bindToPort:12345 error:&err];
[self.socket joinMulticastGroup:@"224.0.1.1" error:&err];
[self.socket beginReceiving:&err];
```

Server

```
self.multicastSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

NSData *d = [@"hello" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[self.multicastSocket sendData:d toHost:@"224.0.1.1" port:12345 withTimeout:-1 tag:11];
```

This works well over wifi. How do I make it work over bluetooth as well? I have googled a bunch and can't find anything... Do I need to create two separate sockets? One bound to the wifi interface and another to the bluetooth interface?

EDIT: or am I confused about something fundamental? This must be possible. GameKit's GKSession does exactly this, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the BT stack access which enables BT over ip protocol.
Also, multicast relies on a network device (router) to manage these groups and registrations. BT requires a concept of ZeroConf networks (which can also work for wifi), but is managed in a peer to peer manner.
Have a look at Bonjour or Dnssd for an implementation closer to the socket level than GameKit.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. You can find pointers to useful information in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844189/bonjour-over-bluetooth-without-gamekit/8273661) or you can use a library such as [HHServices](https://github.com/tolo/HHServices) that wraps this functionality.

I honestly have tried this route with little luck, but I hope this points you in the right direction. [Let me know if you've figured it out!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477813/usage-example-to-connect-two-ios-devices-over-bluetooth-client-server-code)