# Usage example to connect two iOS devices over bluetooth? (client/server code)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, bluetooth, dns-sd

I do not want to use GameKit. I am trying to use a low-level approach using dns_sd.h and methods like [DNSServiceRegister](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844189/bonjour-over-bluetooth-without-gamekit/8273661) to establish and maintain a connection. However, I found a wrapper for this called HHServices... Honestly at this point either a low-level answer using dns_sd or a high-level answer using HHServices is welcome.

Here is [HHServices](https://github.com/tolo/HHServices). Here is [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).

This is the code I have so far. I am able to successfully publish the HHService and the GCDAsyncSocket, and also start browing for HHServices on the other device, but no connection is made. Any help? :D

## Server Side

#### Here's where I publish the HHService:

```
//....
NSUInteger serverPort = 19997;
HHServicePublisher *publisher = [[HHServicePublisher alloc] initWithName:@"MyDisplayName" type:@"_myexampleservice._tcp." domain:@"local." txtData:nil port:serverPort];

GCDAsyncSocket *listenSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![listenSocket acceptOnPort:serverPort error:&error])
{
    [self alert:@"Error starting GCDAsyncsocket"];
}


publisher.delegate = self;
if(![publisher beginPublish])
{
    [self alert:@"Error publishing HHService"];
}
else
{
    [self alert:@"Successfully published HHService"];
}
```

#### This is where I see if a client connected:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket
{
    [self alert:@"didAcceptNewSocket!"];
}
```

---

## Client-side

#### Where I start browsing

```
    HHServiceBrowser *browser = [[HHServiceBrowser alloc] initWithType:@"_myexampleservice._tcp." domain:@"local."];
    browser.delegate = self;
    if(![browser beginBrowse])
    {
        [self alert:@"Couldn't start browsing"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self alert:@"Successfully started browsing"];
    }
```

#### Callback for finding the published HHService:

```
- (void) serviceBrowser:(HHServiceBrowser*)serviceBrowser didFindService:(HHService*)service moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing {
    [self alert:@"Found a service! "];
}
```

Could someone shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HHServices only handles discovery.  It's up to you to make the connection.  You need to resolve the service, then open a socket, like it shows in the HHServices example.

Comment: The thing is, the code [self alert:@"Found a service! "]; doesn't even get called.

Comment: So I basically don't even get the opportunity to resolve the service since it was never discovered.

Comment: You don't post enough context to know for sure, but it looks like your `browser` object might be getting deallocated.  I assume that you are using ARC, your `browser` object is a local variable in a method that return shortly after the code you posted, and that you don't assign that object to any strongly held variable such as an instance variable?

Comment: Yup... that was it. Forgot to retain. I feel stupid now. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not retain my `browser` object.