# How to start with UDP IN IOS OBJECTIVE_C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, udp

Hi to all who visit here.
I am working with xcode proj which use UDP .

So, what i need to do here.

What frameworks i need to include?
How should i start this. ?

In particular, how would I set up a UDP socket and send/receive data over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Markus, the **udpEchoServer** and **udpEchoClient** examples are a very good starting point [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/tree/master/GCD/Xcode).

If you also add the code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621553/how-to-use-gcdasyncudpsocket-for-multicast-over-wifi-and-bluetooth) then you will have a working UDP multicast client + server in no time.