# Sending data from ios device to windows pc over an Bluetooth HID dongle

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, usbserial

**Aim**
I want to pass data from iOS device to a PC using Bluetooth. The data should look as a keyboard input to the desktop. I have been doing some background research about the same and thought of using any HID keyboard emulator dongle. One can pass the data over using the Bluetooth and the dongle will show it as keyboard input to the PC.

**Outcome of some related research:**
Initially I tried to pair an ios device with a windows PC directly. I was unsuccessful. After some research and reading many questions, it turns out that an ios device can only be paired with a MFI( Made for ipad/ipod/iphone) compliant device/accessory, i.e those which have signed NDA with `Apple` and have joined the `MFI` program. It can also ofcourse be paired with a Mac.

**Question:**

- With the release of Bluetooth 4.0, it seems that this restriction
  can be overcome and it can be paired with any device compliant with
  BLE 4.0. Is it so?
- If one can use a Bluetooth to HID keyboard emulator dongle using BLE 4.0, is it possible to pair an iOS device which support BLE 4.0 with it and how?
- Has anyone tried any particular HID keyboard emulator dongle supporting
  BLE 4.0? If yes then any preferences. I came across [Bluegiga USB Dongle](http://ca.mouser.com/new/Bluegiga-Technologies/bluegigabluetoothlemod/) but not sure if it will solve the purpose.

I would be thankful for your input.

Comment: Doing something similar in iOS. Need to connect my iOS to an external hardware using Bluetooth Dongle (BLE HID over Gatt). And i want the Dongle to pass keyboard strokes to iPhone. Is it possible ? Can you explain if it's possible. !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even with a Bluetooth 4.0-compliant device, communication via standard ("high energy") Bluetooth with an iOS device is still only allowed with MFi-compliant devices. Bluetooth Low Energy communication with iOS devices is the part that's now completely open and unrestricted by Apple. If you wish to send data to another computing device (Windows, Mac, Android, etc.), Bluetooth LE is what you're going to need (short of someone reverse-engineering the [Bonjour over Bluetooth PAN connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844189/bonjour-over-bluetooth-without-gamekit)).

As of iOS 6.0, iOS devices can make themselves look like Bluetooth LE peripherals, so desktop computers set up as Bluetooth LE central devices can connect to them. You could put together your own profile for communication, since you'd control the iOS and Windows sides of things, or you could make your iOS device mimic a standard keyboard, heart rate sensor, etc.

As far as compatible dongles, the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859451/recommendation-for-bluetooth-le-usb-adapter-for-macbook-air) list several Bluetooth LE dongles that are known to work with Core Bluetooth on the Mac. The CSR ones seem to be the most frequently cited there and among other people I've talked to. I can't speak for Windows support, but I'd assume there would be driver support there, and I hear Windows 8.1 expands support for Bluetooth LE.

I do have the BLED112 (the Bluegiga USB dongle), and that shows up as a comm port when its drivers are installed. You might talk to that in a slightly different way than you would one of these other Bluetooth LE dongles. I know Bluegiga uses it on the Windows side to capture a little more data than I think you'd normally get from one of these other dongles. The other dongles might present a more universal interface for interacting with Bluetooth LE on the Windows side.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the wonderful answer. I bought a BLED112 USB dongle today. I've already played around with ios ibeacon stuff. It resembles that. What I got from reading the Bluegiga forum was that it acts as a peripheral device and central devices connect to it. My ultimate aim is to preset the USB dongle as an HID device and pass data to it from ios device using Bluetooth. For connecting and sending data to the dongle, how am I supposed to know what are the service in the BLE 4.0 peripheral dongle? What are their UUID? I couldn't find any related support docs or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: With an ios device acting as an iBeacon peripheral device, we program it beforehad. So we know all the services, characteristics and their UUID's. Will I end up to program the USB dongle? 

Thanks a lot for you time Brad. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri - I'm not sure that you'll want to set your BLED112 as a HID peripheral, because I believe those peripherals are intended to be read from, not sent to. For data interchange, I'd recommend setting up a custom profile (Bluegiga has a RS-232 serial communication example that's useful in this regard). The BLED112 is configurable by flashing the firmware on the device (using Bluegiga's BGScript to build the firmware). Bluegiga has pretty good documentation on this process, and BGScript is not hard to learn from their examples.

Comment: Ideally data is read from a peripheral device but a central device is also capable for writing to a characteristic of a peripheral device( provided permissions are given), right? 
If I understand you correctly, I can flash the firmware(using BGScript to build it) of the BLE112 USB and set it up for data interchange, enabling it to show as HID? Other than that is their any better/easier way to show the data being sent from an iOS device as HID input?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri - Right, this can be bidirectional. I just wasn't sure if the HID profile was unidirectional. You can make up your own profile that is. If there's no particular reason to treat it as a HID-compliant device, you can use the serial port replacement example that Bluegiga provides and work off of that. I've done this on a board level (with their DKBLE112 dev board), but haven't tried with the USB dongle. I know you can flash the firmware for that, but I don't know what it provides on the USB side or how you'd interact with that.

Comment: You were right Brad. Although `USB-HID` is mentioned in their product description, I received an email from them stating that their marketing team got ahead of themselves... and device can only enumerates itself as a virtual comm device.