# Is it possible to send Bluetooth data to Android from iOS?

Tags: iphone, android, bluetooth, gamekit

I was wondering if it was possible to make GameKit broadcast data so that an Android device can get the information. I plan on sending XML data, (a Plist, nothing complex) if this is possible. I don't need any confirmation on the iOS device, I just want to send the information.

In theory, Android should be able to receive the raw encoded bytes (or bits) and then the decoding them on Android, becomes my problem, but I can't imaging GameKit broadcasting information until it has a "peer" to send to.

Is it possible to send information from an iOS device to an Android device through bluetooth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible, in principle, for an Android device to interface with an iPhone over Bluetooth/GameKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080644/is-it-possible-in-principle-for-an-android-device-to-interface-with-an-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, 
GameKit requires iOS devices or MFi complaint devices, so it will not even connect with a standard Android or any other device unless it is MFi complaint and thus will not be able to send any data to it.

Comment: its a program from apple where you have to licence technology to develop accessories that can connect to Apple devices. More info here - http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Comment: MFi means: "Made For iPod" (and now the `i` also means iPad as well.)

Answer (score 0):

It IS possiple (by Bluetooth), but you have to be jailbroken and download a package (AirBlue Sharing) from bigboss repo (or *cough*a cracked version*cough*)that allows you to transfer files between that idevice and other non-apple devices via Bluetooth. Here is a link to an article about it:

[JailBreak](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/airblue-sharing-cydia-tweak/)

There is also another similar package called `celeste`, but I haven't looked at it so don't ask me about it.