# use game kit p2p communication between iPhone and Android

Tags: iphone, android, p2p, gamekit

Is there a way to use Game Kit p2p communication between an iPhone and Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible, in principle, for an Android device to interface with an iPhone over Bluetooth/GameKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080644/is-it-possible-in-principle-for-an-android-device-to-interface-with-an-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. GameKit currently only works between iPhones. You'll have to wait for an Android library that spoofs GameKit, or for native Android-support in GameKit. In my opinion, the former is way more likely than the latter.