# iphone: gameKit do not connect to non-Apple device?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, wireless, gamekit

I am developing an iphone/ipad app to connect with other devices through Bluetooth using GameKit, it works fine with iphone/ipad/iPod but it does not work with other platform devices like android or other Bluetooth devices?

Is there any other framework or code available which could connect to other devices through bluetooth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible, in principle, for an Android device to interface with an iPhone over Bluetooth/GameKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080644/is-it-possible-in-principle-for-an-android-device-to-interface-with-an-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - Gamekit is only for iOS devices
If you want to connect to other devices then it should be over standard Bluetooth profiles which both the iOS device and the other device supports

If you are developing accessories that need to connect to iOS devices and want to use your own communication mechanism then you need to join the Apple MFi program and develop accessories as per the MFi program.

Comment: did you mean that by joining I can write an iphone app which could talk to non- apply device or I could develop that device like apple bluetooth parameter to communicate with apple devices?

Comment: @Azhar: by joining MFi program you can write an iPhone app that can talk with "Made for iPhone" electronic accessories, nothing more. Apple MFi Program can't help you to solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use private [BluetoothManager](http://code.google.com/p/shop-deluxe/source/browse/trunk/MyOWNUITableView.backup/MyOWNUITableView.backup/Classes/BluetoothManager.h?r=9) class to connect through Bluetooth to non-Apple devices, but this is not App Store-legal and will cause app rejection.

There are no App Store-permitted options for communicating using Bluetooth with other platforms like Android. They can discover your iPhone if you're using GameKit - and that's all. You can't connect to them, you can't communicate with them.