# File transfer between android and iPhone via bluetooth?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, file-transfer

I was thinking of developing an iPhone and android application so that they can share data between each other via bluetooth. Is it possible? If yes how?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Since the time this question was asked Bluetooth LE has become available and would allow the possibility of swapping files, although slowly.

Answer (score 5):

The Question from user1080731 was - Is it possible to transfer Files Via Bluetooth between Android and iPhone.

And I think that the answer is NO.

The App referred to in the previous responses does not seem to use Bluetooth (the App's description is misleading)
In the demo video for the app - It used Bluetooth when talking between 2 iOS devices, but uses WiFi when talking between Android and iPhone.

in iOS the only possibility is to use the GameKit APIs (primarily meant for peer to peer gaming) to talk to other iOS device using Bluetooth. So you can potentially write an App over this API to do file transfer between iOS devices, (But Gamekit will not work for iOS to  Android)

Answer (score -6):

You can use **File Transfer Profile** of bluetooth for transferring files between bluetooth devices. This is generic for bluetooth not for Operating system(Android, iOS, Windows, etc.).

Coming to your requirement, in both Android and iOS the framework will provide API to use the bluetooth profiles. Just read about bluetooth profiles and OS framework you will get ideas to design your app.

If you are interested, see the **Bluetooth Chat App** available at Android Developers website, you will get good knowledge about how to use bluetooth in Android. But i don't know about iPhone(iOS) framework. I experienced the bluetooth in Android and at firmware development for embedded products. If you want more in formation about bluetooth profiles [see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile)

I hope it may help you.

Comment: iOS does not support File Transfer Profile The Question is how to transfer between iPhone and Android

Comment: hi Yugandhar Babu ...i want to exchange some information via Bluetooth with pairing of 2 android devices with authentication only.. i have seen the android chat sample example available in android developer side ..its work well but now i want after Bluetooth pairing of 2 devices , want to exchange some information to each other as when a device send  its some information to other devise a authentication pop up would be appear to remote  device and if it accepted then only share information to  other side...vv thanks in adv