# Sharing files over bluetooth in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth, file-sharing

I would like to develop an iOS application that send files between other devices over bluetooth. The app should be able to recieve data from other (non)iOS devices and save it locally.

My question: Is this possible and allowed by Apple, and if so: Where can I find a good tutorial about this? 
The only things I find using google are on jailbroken phones, which is not something I am looking for.

Comment: No it is not possible.
See my response to this [Question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707753/file-transfer-between-android-and-iphone-via-bluetooth/8709264#8709264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible.
See my response to this [Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8709130/379445)

The only possibility is using GameKit APis to talk with two iOS devices and writing your own file transfer protocol over it to send the files.

Comment: I just got this send to me, http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/iPhoneBluetooth Any experience with that or doesn't it work use that either?

Comment: I think it needs jail broken iPhone see this - http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/GettingStarted