# Connect with Bluetooth GKSession to No-iOS Devices

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, bluetooth

just a simple question:

Is that possible to connect with Bluetooth using GKSession to "No-iOS" Devices like Android or some custom Bluetooth device ?
I didn't find any information about this... I found only "iOS" bluetooth connections info.
If it's not possible, i would like to know how can i do it anyway.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, according to apple's [GKSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A GKSession object provides the ability to discover and connect to
>   nearby **iOS devices** using Bluetooth or Wi-fi.

Plus how are you going to implement the [GKSessionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSessionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/GKSessionDelegate) protocol out of iOS? You cant.

Comment: Is there other way to do it ? instead of GKSession ?

Comment: I am afraid not, Apple will never let this happen, anyway check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080644/is-it-possible-in-principle-for-an-android-device-to-interface-with-an-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707753/file-transfer-between-android-and-iphone-via-bluetooth